# How I transform. Ram%Rohim%Sam : 21 to Ram:21. Rohim:21 Sam:21 in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I solve this

```
Ram%Rohim%Sam : 21
```

to

```
Ram:21
Rohim:21
Sam:21
```

How can I solve this using python

Comment: Was there a problem when you tried to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to replace % with 21?
If 21 is not a variable i.e. it stays the same:

```py
start = "Ram%Rohim%Sam:21"
end = start.replace("%", "21")
```

and if it is a variable:

```py
num = 21
start = "Ram%Rohim%Sam : 21"
end = start.format("%", num)
```

Just to make sure, are you using Python 3.6 or higher? 2.7 hasn't been updated since last year - it has been deprecated afaik.